# Deployment of ASP.NET Core Web API to PLESK

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, hosting, plesk, windows-server, asp.net-core-7.0

This is my `web.config` file (ASP.NET Core 7.0) :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Test.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In this case I get a 404 error. But when I send request with Postman, I get the response.

If I remove this config:

```
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
```

`Index.html` page entered as the website default page. But in this case when I send request with Postman, I can't get a response.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's you asp.net core application? MVC or Web API? If you are using the MVC, there is no need to add the default html.

Comment: Thi is API app.

Comment: If this is API App, why you want a default html page? Besides, if you want to add a default html page, you should put it inside the asp.net core wwwroot folder and enable the statfic file middleware inside the program.cs

Comment: Default html page is the my react app index.html. And you write i do this. Add index.html to wwwroot folder. Now everything is working) Thanks

Comment: If you feel my reply helped you and answer you question, I will convert the comment to the answer . please mark it and this will help other folks who face the same issue could find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a default html page, you should put it inside the asp.net core wwwroot folder and enable the static file middleware inside the program.cs.

Like below:

[image]

Program.cs

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
//Use to host html pages.
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

to use backend of ASP.Net-Core-WebAPI with Angular frontend, follow these steps:

on 'program.cs':

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
...
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value?.StartsWith("/api") == false, builder =>
{
    builder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //  spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        //}
    });
});
```

then publish your angular app:

```
ng build --configuration production
```

put backend files on 'Home directory/httpdocs/'

[image: asp.net core web-api files on PLESK]

and put angualr files on 'Home directory/httpdocs/ClientApp/dist'

[image]

ps; don't need to change 'web.config'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Test.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"><environmentVariables/></aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```